# Ubuntu 18.04 -> 20.04 alt-tab gets slow / laggy after a while

Tags: gnome, 20.04

I recently updated to 20.04 LTS from 18.04 LTS.
When my system is up for like a day, <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> starts to lag. Not the window switcher panel, but when I select the window I want and release keys, it takes maybe a second to switch.
Rebooting or restarting gnome with `killall -SIGQUIT gnome-shell` fixes it back.
I also noticed gnome-shell was constantly at ~10% CPU while after restart, it's ~3%. Not sure if related.
I couldn't find anything about this problem. Any ideas on how can I fix, or further troubleshoot this?

```
GNOME Shell 3.36.2<br>
nvidia-driver-440<br>
5.5.13-050513-generic
```

Comment: I have the same issue, I believe it might be related to the nvidia drivers. Currently downgrading to 390 to see if that helps

Comment: `killall` works! Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't have nvdia and I also have this issue. I'm on Radeon vega graphics AMD chip. by the way thanks for the `killall` trick. you saving my life. I am not using the proprietary drivers in my case. i will install them and see what happens.

Comment: You can also restart gnome via Alt+F2 -> type "r" -> Enter -> Boom. Seems like a Gnome bug.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue after migrating from 18.04 to 20.04, but I am using lightdm.
Downgrading the nvidia-driver to 390 and restarting my machine solved the issue.

You can follow [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/) link on how to update your drivers, but instead of the newest, choose an older one.

I only tried 390 so far, but a newer version might work as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu Mate, unchecking `Windows->Show thumbnails in Alt-tab` saved me for now.

I prefer not viewing Thumbnails than having all this lag.

[Ref](https://makandracards.com/makandra/47066-ubuntu-mate-fixing-alt-+-tab-being-really-slow)